# How to list desired excel row and column with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Friends I'm not able to get only the first Invisible value from the Status column, or only the 'No. Hydrometer' value from the Elemento column, or all the values.
Friends my spreadsheet is configured like this.

|    Elemento    | Status   |
| Nº Hidrômetro  |Invisível |
| Leitura        |Invisível |
| Diâmetro do HD |Invisível |
| Filtro         |Invisível |

```
I need to get the following values:
-- Only the Status column with the value in the first row equal to 'Invisible'
-- All values ​​in the Status column only
-- All values ​​in Element column only
-- All values ​​in rows and columns

require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open('C:/temp/pasta1.xls', "r")
sheet = book.worksheet 0
pp sheet.row(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| element | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Visible |
| 2 | Invisible |

```
>> book = Spreadsheet.open("excel.xls", "r")
>> sheet = book.worksheet(0)
>> element_column = sheet.first.find_index("element")
=> 0
>> status_column = sheet.first.find_index("status")
=> 1
```

Only the Status column with the value in the first row equal to 'Invisible'

```
>> sheet.detect { |row| row[status_column] =~ /invisible/i }&.fetch(status_column)
=> "Invisible"
```

All values ​​in the Status column only

```
>> sheet.column(status_column).to_a[1..]
=> ["Visible", "Invisible"]
```

All values ​​in Element column only

```
>> sheet.column(element_column).to_a[1..]
=> [1, 2]
```

All values ​​in rows and columns

```
>> sheet.rows[1..]
=> [[1, "Visible"], [2, "Invisible"]]
```

---

*https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md#reading-is-easy*